# What is the difference between Ubuntu Mate and Linux Mint Mate?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, mate-desktop, ubuntu-mate

What would be the key deciding factors for me to decide whether to install Ubuntu Mate or Linux Mint Mate?

Comment: One runs Ubuntu underneath and the other runs Linux Mint underneath.

Comment: [MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATE_(software)) is a desktop environment. It can be installed on various Linux-based operating systems. Ubuntu MATE is an Ubuntu flavor using the MATE desktop environment. Linux Mint is available in multiple variants, each with a specific desktop environment; the most widely used are Linux Mint Cinnamon and Linux Mint MATE. To decide, choose between more widely available support (where Ubuntu wins, but most of the knowledge about Ubuntu applies to Mint too) and somewhat better out of the box experience (where it is said that Linux Mint wins).

Comment: @AlexP I understand that MATE is a desktop environment. Also from what I understand Linux Mint is derived from Ubuntu. So hence my question since Linux Mint MATE is derived from Ubuntu with the MATE DE what is the difference from Ubuntu MATE in terms of system resource requirements, available applications, support, etc.

Comment: Linux Mint MATE is not Ubuntu with the MATE desktop environment, it's Linux Mint with the MATE desktop environment. Mint is based on Ubuntu, and Ubuntu is based on Debian. Hence most knowledge about Debian also applies to Ubuntu and Mint, and most knowledge about Ubuntu also applies to Mint. Mint makes a great effort to "just work" out of the box. There is very little difference between resource consumption between Ubuntu 16.04 and Mint. All (or almost all) applications available on one are also available on the other. Some default apps are different, some default fonts are different, etc.

Comment: Why the unaccept of the answer?

Comment: @fabby since I had to change my question the answer was not responding what the reworded question asked. That is why I thought it would be wise to un-accept the answer until something more in line to the new reworded question. But apparently the question has been closed so rewording didn't help.

Comment: That's indeed a totally different question. The first one was borderline off-topic, but this one shouldn't be... If I were you, I'd roll back my edit and ask a new questions instead of trying to fit a totally new question into an existing question... For your information: the system here doesn't advertise when a question gets radically changed... Just ask a new one.  It's not like you're being charged more if you click `/ask question`  **;-)  :-)**

Comment: OK, rolled back to original question. Will consider asking a new question which is more on-topic for this forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) is an official Ubuntu *[flavour](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours)* that [Canonical](https://www.canonical.com) (The company behind Ubuntu) has deemed worthy of carrying the Ubuntu name as it not only uses Ubuntu but also contributes to Ubuntu.

Linux Mint is based upon Ubuntu, but does not adhere to the Canonical standards, thus cannot be called Ubuntu, and Linux Mint Mate is a flavour of Linux Mint.

***Now, what is the difference to you?***

Well, if you ask your questions here, there really is none, but if you intend to ask questions on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) about Linux Mint Mate, they will close your questions and tell you to ask your questions here if you use any variant of Linux Mint (including the Mate version)...

As to the key deciding factors, well those are totally subjective, so off-topic here and totally up to you.

Answer (score 4):

The only packages that are in the Mint (18.2 serena dist) main pool are:

`blueberry, caja-folder-color-switcher, cinnamon-core, cinnamon-desktop-environment, cinnamon-themes, folder-color-switcher, grub2-theme-mint, ia32-libs, iso-flag-png, libreoffice-style-mint, linux-kernel-generic, linuxmint-keyring, mate-desktop-environment, mate-desktop-environment-core, mint-artwork-cinnamon, mint-artwork-common, mint-artwork-gnome, mint-artwork-kde, mint-artwork-mate, mint-artwork-xfce, mint-backgrounds-maya, mint-backgrounds-nadia, mint-backgrounds-olivia, mint-backgrounds-petra, mint-backgrounds-qiana, mint-backgrounds-rafaela, mint-backgrounds-rebecca, mint-backgrounds-retro, mint-backgrounds-rosa, mint-backgrounds-sarah, mint-backgrounds-serena, mint-backgrounds-xfce, mint-common, mint-dev-tools, mint-info-cinnamon, mint-info-kde, mint-info-mate, mint-info-xfce, mint-mdm-themes, mint-mdm-themes-gdm, mint-mdm-themes-html, mint-meta-cinnamon, mint-meta-codecs, mint-meta-codecs-core, mint-meta-codecs-kde, mint-meta-core, mint-meta-kde, mint-meta-mate, mint-meta-xfce, mint-mirrors, mint-themes, mint-themes-gtk3, mint-translations, mint-upgrade-info, mint-user-guide-cinnamon, mint-user-guide-kde, mint-user-guide-mate, mint-user-guide-xfce, mint-x-icons, mint-y-icons, mint-y-theme, mintbackup, mintdesktop, mintdrivers, mintinstall, mintinstall-icons, mintlocale, mintmenu, mintnanny, mintstick, mintsystem, mintupdate, mintupload, mintwelcome, nemo-folder-color-switcher, nvidia-prime-applet, rhythmbox-plugin-tray-icon, syslinux-themes-linuxmint-cinnamon, syslinux-themes-linuxmint-kde, syslinux-themes-linuxmint-mate, syslinux-themes-linuxmint-xfce, ubiquity-slideshow-mint, ubiquity-slideshow-mint-kde, ubuntu-system-adjustments`

Everything else is straight Ubuntu, from the Ubuntu mirror set.

Basically it comes down to default config, artwork, etc.

A Mint 18.x desktop *looks* better on first boot than an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, even with MATE installed on the Ubuntu system.